# CSS - Show only a percentage of a responsive image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show only a percentage of an image (say, the top half), but in a responsive way so that resizing the viewport doesn't affect what portion of the image is shown.

[JSFiddle attempt](https://jsfiddle.net/qse2LL4b/)

The only solutions I've found rely on using a fixed height for the image (say, 200px) rather than a %age, but this isn't responsive. As you shrink the viewport, more and more of the image shows until you eventually see the entire image.

---

Note: My JSFiddle example is using the bootstrap class `img-responsive`, which adds the following CSS properties:

```
display: block
max-width: 100%;
height: auto
```

You can also grab the middle divider/handlebar in the JSFiddle and move it around to see the effect on the image.

---

What can be done to meet my requirements? Is it even possible without JavaScript and with browser support down to IE9?

Comment: Post both your existing html and css

Comment: It's in the JSFiddle

Comment: meh, canvas might be a good solution

Comment: when using height as a % it's referring to the height of the parent element, since there is no parent element it's making it 50% of the size of the page.

Comment: What is the canvas solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div img {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -50%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mazenl77/I-like-buttons-3a/512/Cute-Ball-Go-icon.png" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, I threw this together for you: https://jsfiddle.net/qse2LL4b/4/

```
function showPart(img, offsetTop, offsetLeft, width, height){
  var src = img.src;
    $(img).replaceWith("<canvas id='cnvs' style='max-width:100%;'></canvas>");
  var canvas = document.getElementById('cnvs');
  canvas.height = height;
  canvas.width = width;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(this, offsetLeft, offsetTop, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
  };
  img.src = src;
}
```

It takes the source of your image and crops it and replaces it. You can add the im-responsive class to the "canvas" element in the function if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pseudo-element :after in addition to position: absolute.

```
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qse2LL4b/3/

Comment: but as you shrink the viewport, the image disappears eventually...not what was asked...and you fiddle link is the same as the original

Comment: Fixed fiddle link.

Comment: Nice solution. Can you explain a little how it works?

Comment: div:after reacts like a normal element inside the div container. div container is set as `position: relative` so the :after element starts from the top and is 50% height. If you want to show the top half you only need to change the `top: 0` in `bottom: 0` so that is starts from the bottom.

Comment: I just realized that you're masking the top half of the image with a white background. Unfortunately that top half is still taking up space, which is problematic. If you put a header above the image, you'll have a bunch of empty space before seeing the image.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You could add `margin-top: -50%;` to free this space. https://jsfiddle.net/qse2LL4b/5/